# select inside loop in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I know in mysql we need to avoid select inside loop.

I need to fetch data from firebase, from 2 "tables", and I do this:

```
// first get post ids from feed:
var feedRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Feed').child("-idownner").limitToLast(10);

feedRef.once('value', async function(snapshot) {

            snapshot.forEach((subChild) => { // start the loop

                var value = subChild.val();
                value = value.postID;

                //inside foreach loop select from posts: <<<---------------
                var post = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + value).orderByKey();

                promises.push(new Promise((res, rej) => {
                    post.once('value', function(snapshot2) {
                        var obj = Object.assign(snapshot2.val(), { key: snapshot2.key });
                        res(obj);
                    });
                }));
            });
```

my question here is, is my "join" correctly? can I "select" inside loop in firebase like this? if it is wrong, is there another way to get this data?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, nesting the loading of the items from the second table is the normal way to do a client-side join with Firebase. But you don't need to create your own promise, as `once()` already returns a promise.

So you can simplify it to something like:

```
promises.push(
    post.once('value').then((snapshot2) => Object.assign(snapshot2.val(), { key: snapshot2.key })
);
```

---

I'm not entirely sure what the `Object.assign` is supposed to do, but suspect you can simplify that to:

```
promises.push(
    post.once('value').then((snapshot2) => { ...snapshot2.val(), key: snapshot2.key })
);
```